# 12.04 sudo testparm -s smb.conf.master >smb.conf fails on permsissions

Tags: samba, sudo

When I run

```
sudo testparm -s smb.conf.master >smb.conf 
bash: smb.conf: Permission denied
```

I just need a simple samba configuration to share files among 4 linux machines behind a router on a very small LAN and am attempting to use the same configuration file for all four machines.

The files are all owned by root.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo bash
```

Then:

```
testparm -s smb.conf.master > smb.conf
```

It worked for me.